# How do I start the docker daemon on macOS?

Tags: macos, daemons, docker

I am using macOS 10.14.6 and `docker info` shows me that the docker daemon is not running.

How do I start the docker daemon from terminal?

I have not found any information on doing so anywhere. On Linux you do something like `sudo service docker stop`, but this is incompatible with MacOS.

Comment: https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1825 This is for windows, see if helpful here [Cannot connect to the Docker daemon on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44084846/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-on-macos?rq=1) is for macOS [Mac OS X sudo docker Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193300/mac-os-x-sudo-docker-cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-is-the-docker-daemon-r?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: What's the actual output you get from `docker info`? And what versions of docker, docker-compose, and docker-machine do you have installed? You need to make sure they're compatible with the Docker app.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

The docker setup does not work as in a normal Linux machine, on a Mac it is much more complicated. But it can be done!

1. `brew install --cask docker virtualbox`
2. `brew install docker-machine`
3. `docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default`
4. `docker-machine restart`
5. `eval "$(docker-machine env default)"` # This might throw an `TSI connection` error. In that case run `docker-machine regenerate-certs default`
6. (`docker-machine restart`) # maybe needed
7. `docker run hello-world`

These steps are based on information given in these two questions:

- [Cannot connect to the Docker daemon on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44084846/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-on-macos)
- [Mac OS X sudo docker Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36193300/mac-os-x-sudo-docker-cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-is-the-docker-daemon-r?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: I tried this and at the `docker-machine create` step it just got hung up "waiting for an IP" indefinitely, left the machine / VM in a locked unusable state.

Comment: I tried these instructions, but the docker daemon still wasn't started... To resolve the problem I had to use `open --background -a Docker` on my macbook...

Comment: Instead of `brew install --cask docker virtualbox`, I had to do `brew install --cask virtualbox`. Otherwise, when later running `docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default`, I got `Error with pre-create check: "VBoxManage not found. Make sure VirtualBox is installed and VBoxManage is in the path"`, which [indicates VirtualBox isn't properly installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45836296/error-with-pre-create-check-vboxmanage-not-found-make-sure-virtualbox-is-inst).

Comment: This went great for some time. But `docker-machine` was [moved to maintenance](https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/4537) in 2018, with a last release in 2019. They replaced it with [Docker Desktop](https://github.com/docker/for-mac)

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't want to install virtualbox on an M1 processor based computer (which makes sense, since VB is Intel based).

Answer (score 78):

An alternative solution is to use other runtime for docker. For example
[colima](https://github.com/abiosoft/colima)

```
brew install colima
colima start
docker ps -a
```

Since docker desktop isn't free for enterprise usage, the alternative runtime is a good option.

**NOTE**: if you've previously used Docker Desktop for launching Docker daemon and had an export of `DOCKER_HOST` defined in your user's shell configuration (`.bash_profile`, `.zsh_profile` etc.), you need to re-specify `DOCKER_HOST` to make sure it points to `.colima` directory and commands like `docker-compose up -d` work properly.

Example:

```bash
export DOCKER_HOST=unix:///$HOME/.colima/docker.sock
```

Comment: https://rancherdesktop.io/ is another option, offering less functionalities than docker desktop though

Comment: This one was the only solution on MacOs. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It works! Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks. Before, `colima start`, I had to run `brew install docker`. And then, everything went fine.

Answer (score 38):

Here is an alternative solution which worked for me:

- remove docker and docker-compose installed by brew
- install [Docker Desktop for Mac](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install/) or use  `brew install homebrew/cask/docker`
- run it and pass admin credentials to start everything

It resolved issues with "docker daemon not running" as well as some other issues that the other answer didn't (e.g. `0.0.0.0` ports were not redirected with docker installed using brew and worked smoothly with Docker Desktop installation).

Answer (score 28):

If you have Docker Desktop installed, the docker daemon will be launched if you launch Docker Desktop.

To do that, you can run in Terminal:

```
open -a Docker
```

Also, if you don't like the window pop-up at startup, you can disable it by unchecking:

> "Preferences" (via gear icon on the Docker Desktop window) -> "General" -> "Open Docker Dashboard at startup"

Comment: You have my vote already, but just for fun, and to save a precious keystroke, it works with a lower-case `d` too, i.e. `open -a docker` 

Comment: Cool, it's so easy to remember too. Open a docker.

Answer (score 3):

Just install "Docker Desktop" and configure it to start when you log in.

- You can find Docker Desktop here: https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop/
- Install and configure as follow: "Settings" > "General" > and check "Start Docker Desktop when you log in"

Comment: Gotta love the simple answers. Not sure why I didn't think to look in settings earlier. Also +1 to @catwith for the comment about disabling the Docker dashboard window that opens on startup.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I start the docker daemon from terminal [ on MacOS ] ?

### TL;DR

I use a combination of [`open`](https://ss64.com/osx/open.html), and [`docker info`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/info/) to start the docker daemon from terminal on MacOS.

```bash
open -a docker && while ! docker info > /dev/null 2>&1; do sleep 1 ; done
```

### For the curious

First, we open the Docker application by passing `docker` to the `-a` or application flag of the `open` [command](https://ss64.com/osx/open.html#:%7E:text=arg1%20...%5D%0A%0AKey-,%2Da,-application%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20The%20application).

```bash
open -a docker
```

For me, the engine takes a few seconds to actually boot, so I run `docker info` until it returns an exit code of 0 ( or success ).

```bash
while ! docker info; do sleep 1 ; done
```

Since I don't like seeing the terminal output while waiting, I redirect it to [`/dev/null`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/null.4.html). I want to capture errors and output alike, so I pass `2>&1` which says to send standard error and standard output to the same place.

```bash
> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Finally, we get the command.

```bash
open -a docker && while ! docker info > /dev/null 2>&1; do sleep 1 ; done
```