# Running docker daemon on Apple Silicon without Docker Desktop

Tags: virtualization, apple-silicon, docker

[Docker desktop](https://www.docker.com/products/docker-desktop) is about to become a paid service for larger businesses on January 31st, 2022. On Apple Silicon / M1 chips previous solutions (usually relying on VirtualBox) to run the docker daemon using the cli only such as those in [How do I start the docker daemon on macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/373888/how-do-i-start-the-docker-daemon-on-macos) do not work.

What's the best option for those of us whose companies don't want to fork out the subscription fee?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to avoid the problem by switching to [podman](https://podman.io/getting-started/) and adding

```
alias docker=podman
```

to my `.bashrc`. Check out this answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/672202/152879).

There also seems to be a [compose solution](https://github.com/containers/podman-compose).

Building and running container works like a charm. I can keep on using my old Dockerfiles.
Also pulling from official and private Container Registries is no problem.

Mounting local folders as volumes was [actively worked on](https://github.com/containers/podman/issues/8016) when this question was first answered, and now it is [fully working](https://medium.com/@butkovic/favoring-podman-over-docker-desktop-33368e031ba0).

Comment: Thank you, the mount problems are causing quite a few headaches, but this does seem to be the best solution so far.

Answer (score 2):

I installed
https://rancherdesktop.io/
to start the docker daemon. You can check that the Docker daemon is indeed started by typing:

```
docker info
```

and use it along things like

```
watch docker ps
```

and

```
docker exec -it 151e9b2e4347 /bin/sh
```

in console windows since these links do not exist in rancher desktop.
Rancher desktop doesn't offer as many functionalities as docker desktop.