# Installing VirtualBox on AWS EC2 OS X instance

Tags: install, ssh, virtualbox, docker, aws

For a CICD pipeline purpose, we are attempting to setup CI runner -> install Docker and hence VirtualBox on an Amazon AWS EC2 OS X instance, and getting failure at the very last stage of validating and running package scripts as:

> installer: The install failed. (The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance. An error occurred while running scripts from the package “VirtualBox.pkg”.)

We are aware of the kernel extensions requirements needed for VirtualBox and which can be granted by running system in recovery mode and setting up the relevant things, but we are currently not able to boot the 'SSH'd EC2 instance into recovery mode and set the relevant flags, nor we can do that using UI since its all on terminal.

Are we using the correct approach? Is there any workaround for the same (Docker without VirtualBox or alternatives etc.)

References: 
[How do I start the docker daemon on macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/373888/how-do-i-start-the-docker-daemon-on-macos) 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44084846/cannot-connect-to-the-docker-daemon-on-macos

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  What is the link to your CI runner? Might be much easier to run your container on AWS and just have the Mac call out over the network group. I would probably start from the bottom up on this or look into parallels instead of VBox as it will save you a ton of time and you’ll have pro support

Comment: I know Docker Desktop uses [hyperkit](https://github.com/moby/hyperkit) which uses xhyve - can the docker engine use xhyve? Possibly using https://gist.github.com/bitjockey42/0d5303b787a449cd564f

Comment: Thanks for your inputs! As a workaround though, we have set a mac runner executor as a shell directly, rather than docker, so now we are able to build project and hence the pipeline by direct project commands.